# ASP.NET MVC to PHP Laravel Migration: Html.RenderAction Alternative

Tags: asp.net-mvc, laravel, laravel-5, renderaction

I'm currently developing a CMS using PHP Laravel (5.4) based on an existing ASP.NET MVC version I've made in the past. Since most of the ASP.NET version is written in JS, I'm trying to reuse the most I can in the newer Laravel version I'm developing. I have already translated most of the C# code to PHP, thanks to Laravel's similarities with ASP.NET MVC architecture, this was somewhat straightforward.

Currently I'm facing a issue  trying to call a controller action from within a view that will in-turn render a partial view. In the ASP.NET MVC version I've accomplished this using a `Html.RenderAction` helper.

ASP.NET MVC Example:

```
<div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Controller", "Action");}
</div>
```

I want know if there is any alternative to the `Html.RenderAction` helper that I can use to accomplish this task.

I've search the interwebs and Laravel's documentation, and from what I was able to find, View Composers seem to be closest alternative. Unfortunately, I didn't find any example that could resolve my issue.

@Farrukh suggested using View Composers and it does actually work as intended. The problem is that I will need to add a View Composer to the AppServiceProvider for every partial view I want to render.

I found another solution that allows me to call an action from a view and render a partial view:

```
<?php echo \App\Http\Controllers\PageController::listAll(); ?>
```

But this solution doesn't seem very clean.

Answer (score 1):

ViewComposer behaves like a global component, all you have to do is put your business logic into a method in your Model.

e.g.

```
class Post extends Model {
    public static function archives() {
        return static::selectRaw('your query here')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
    }
}
```

Then goto providers/AppServiceProvider.php

add your viewcomposer code into boot method (a hook before any view loads).

e.g.

```
@include('layouts.sidebar')
```

in AppServiceProvier, boot method:

```
public function boot() {
    view()->composer('layouts.sidebar', function($view) {
        $view->with('archives', \App\Post::archives());
    });
}
```

Comment: this solves my main issue, but know i have a problem, a need to create a view composer inside the AppServiceProvider for every partial view i want to use. Isn't there a simpler way to call an action from the view?

Comment: For example, i'm able to call an action from a view like this: <?php echo \App\Http\Controllers\PageController::listAll(); ?> but it doesn't seem very 'clean'... updated my question.

Comment: you can make your own providers.

    php artisan make:provider YourProviderName

for every entity / object / operation

Comment: Going to look at Laravel's service providers. I'll get back to you sooon :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Service Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#service-injection):

```
<div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Controller", "Action");}
</div>
```

In Laravel would be:

```
@inject('Controller', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeOrOtherController')
{!! $Controller->action() !!}.
```

With this you will render in the view the content of the view of the action in the controller.